# How to implement Denial of Service attack optimal strategies in Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, java-ee-6, embedded-jetty, jetty-8

What are the optimal ways to implement Denial Of Service attack protection in Jetty. What all classes need to be extended or configuration need to be setup.

Answer (score 5):

Use A Dos Filter http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/DoSFilter.
To enable it in Jetty.xml you would insert this code

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>DoSFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.DoSFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
     <param-name>maxRequestsPerSec</param-name>
     <param-value>30</param-value>
   </init-param>
</filter>
```